# Issue with setting up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm in the process of setting up a development environment for SharePoint 2010 on a Windows Server 2008 machine. I installed the prerequisites fo Sharepoint 2010 and ran a Windows Update. Now when I run the setup.exe I keep on getting the message saying that:

**Setup is unable to proceed due to the folloiwng error(s):
This prodcut requires the Windows Indentity Foundation**.

I downloaded the file to install the Windows Identity Foundation (Windows6.1-KB974405-x64) and when I run the file I keep on getting the message saying that:

**The update does not apply to your system.**

This is frustrating, I really need to get this going for a project that needs to be developed in Sharepoint 2010, any help or tips are most appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The error "The update does not apply to your system" simply means that your system doesn't support Sharepoint Development. Please note that Sharepoint requires following minimum configurations.

1. **Processor**>>64-bit, four cores.
2. **RAM**>>4 GB for developer or evaluation use and 8 GB for production and server use.
3. **Hard disk**>>80 GB for system drive.

That being said, please make sure you are using an operating system that is latest to Microsoft Windows Vista (Service Pack 2).

Comment: I was finally able to run the setup by downloading and running the Windows6.0-KB974405-x64 file. Thanks.